# Get alias name of AWS Lambda function in code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I implement AWS Lambda function on Java using [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java) and [AWS Lambda Java Support Libraries](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs) and in some cases I need to get name, version and alias of current function right in code of the function.

Name and version I can get from [Context](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/Context.java) using getFunctionName() and getFunctionVersion() methods. But how can I get current alias value?

Comment: Did you try this , https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetAlias.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `Context` object passed into the lambda handler to get that data.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-context-object.html

> The context object properties are:
>
> getMemoryLimitInMB(): Memory limit, in MB, you configured for the
>   Lambda function.
>
> getFunctionName(): Name of the Lambda function that is running.
>
> getFunctionVersion(): The Lambda function version that is executing.
>   If an alias is used to invoke the function, then getFunctionVersion
>   will be the version the alias points to.
>
> getInvokedFunctionArn(): The ARN used to invoke this function. It can
>   be function ARN or alias ARN. An unqualified ARN executes the $LATEST
>   version and aliases execute the function version it is pointing to.